# Problema con Envío de Email en Django

Tags: python, django

Tengo un problema al enviar un email desde `Django`, me sale
el siguiente error:

> SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.

En mi entorno de pruebas esto funciona sin ningún problema, pero al
llevarlo a producción en un servidor `Centos 7` con `Apache` y `mod_wsgi`,
me sale el error.

He hecho un pequeño script en `python` para probar solamente el
funcionamiento del envío de correos, sin meter a Django en el tema y
me aparece lo siguiente:

> send: 'STARTTLS\r\n'
>
> reply: '502 5.5.2 Error: command not recognized\r\n'
>
> reply: retcode (502); Msg: 5.5.2 Error: command not recognized
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "prueba_correo.py", line 16, in
>
> server.login(username,password)
>
> File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 584, in login
>
> raise SMTPException("SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.")

He probado el mismo script en otra computadora y me envía el correo
sin ningún problema.

Comment: Hola, ¿puedes mostrar tu script?

Answer (score 1):

trata de enviarlo con php

```
  mail("correo@destinatario.com","asunto","mensaje");
```

si no funciona tu servidor tiene que tener alguna clase de bloqueo smtp o algo por el estilo.

Comment: Es muy probable que sea lo que me dices, no he probado con PHP, porque no tengo mucho conocimiento del mismo, pero ya veo que la solución va por arreglar el tema de smtp.